# Push Notifications still play sounds when I don't register it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification, ios8

My problem is, I register for badge and alert only, but sound is still played from the server.
I am able to receive push notifications, but the sound is still being played. I decided to check settings on my device and it doesn't make sense. It shows sounds in the include section, but once I click on it there is no on/off switch for sounds.

Check screenshots for references. Any suggestions will be appreciated?

Here is my code.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                     |UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

return YES;

 }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
 {

 [application registerForRemoteNotifications];

 }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to your device setting -> Notification Center .In this panel all the applications are registered for which Push Notifications are enabled. Select your required application -> then a new wizard is opened where Sound is placed with switch icon. Here you can on off notification sound.

Second one is :-
In your notification script which is uploaded on your server in that code do some change in payload array like 'sound' => 'Nill'. It wil Works.